# Arithmetic expansion through ssh and zsh -lc throws parse error

Tags: shell, zsh

I'm attempting the following:

```bash
❯ ssh user1@10.8.1.1 zsh --version
zsh 5.8.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin22.0)

❯ ssh user1@10.8.1.1 zsh -lc "for ((index=1; index <= 1; index++)); do echo \$index; done"
zsh:1: parse error near `)'
```

Yet locally and also without `zsh -lc` through ssh, it works:

```bash
❯ zsh -lc "for ((index=1; index <= 1; index++)); do echo $index; done"
1
❯ ssh user1@10.8.1.1 "for ((index=1; index <= 1; index++)); do echo \$index; done"
1
```

I can also get it to work when I do anything before the for loop:

```bash
❯ ssh user1@10.8.1.1 zsh -lc "echo 1; for ((index=1; index <= 1; index++)); do echo \$index; done"

1
```

Any recommendations on where I should look?

Comment: Please don't tag a question with both bash and zsh. One or the other; they're not mutually compatible in general. (I'm coming at this from the bash side; people trying to run code that works fine in zsh on bash is a frequent source of bugs / questions in IRC support channels; zsh deliberately chooses to break POSIX compatibility in places where POSIX made bad decisions that make correct code harder to write, but that means that people following zsh practices and then trying to run the resulting code in bash are writing code with pervasive but often-subtle bugs).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's also word splitting by the destination shell which you want to avoid. So quoting once more should work:

```
ssh user1@10.8.1.1 "zsh -lc 'for ((index=1; index <= 1; index++)); do echo \$index; done'"
```

Comment: One could move the opening double quotes to just before the `zsh` to be a little more clear about what's going on under the hood. (That is: `ssh user1@10.8.1.1 "zsh -lc 'for ((index=1; index <= 1; index++)); do echo \$index; done'"` exposes to readers how ssh is running this command, by passing a single string over the wire to be interpreted by the remote user's default shell).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks for the suggestion; upvote for your detailed answer!

Answer (score 3):

ssh only passes **one string** to the remote shell. Not a list of individual arguments -- a single string. When you pass it multiple arguments, it just concatenates them with a space to generate that string; it thus makes it easier to think about this in terms that result in correct results when you generate a single string yourself (with the `zsh` and the `-lc` both as parts of that string).

Both the approaches below avoid any need to do hand-escaping: you're never responsible as a human for knowing that you need to change `$index` to `\$index`, or deciding how to re-escape it to get through an extra shell (be it local or remote).

---

#### Ensuring that *only* zsh can see/parse/munge the code you're passing

The ideal approach, if you don't know what the default remote shell is and the code you're running doesn't read from stdin, is to pass code on stdin so it only goes over the wire *after* the remote copy of zsh is started:

```
# define a function so we can use declare -f to serialize the code
rmtfunc() { for ((index=1; index <= 1; index++)); do echo $index; done; }

# make the remote shell start zsh before code is passed to it
ssh user1@10.8.1.1 zsh -l <<EOF
$(declare -f rmtfunc); rmtfunc
EOF
```

That way you can also use `$(declare -p varname)` to pass local variables over the wire, and ensure that their values are parsed *by zsh*, without any other shell in the way first.

---

#### If the remote shell is compatible enough, a fallback that keeps stdin clear

```
# declare a function with the code we want to run remotely
rmtfunc() { for ((index=1; index <= 1; index++)); do echo $index; done; }

# use printf %q to serialize that into a string
printf -v ssh_cmd '%q ' zsh -lc "$(declare -f rmtfunc); rmtfunc"

# pass that string as an argument to ssh
ssh user1@10.8.1.1 "$ssh_cmd"
```

That'll work fine if the remote shell is anything with ksh extensions -- not just zsh but also bash &c -- but might fail if `printf %q` used `$'\t'` or `$'\n'` syntax to escape a tab or a newline. You can avoid that by using the earlier approach that passes code direct to zsh on stdin.

---

#### Explaining What Went Wrong

When you run...

```
ssh user1@10.8.1.1 zsh -lc "for ((index=1; index <= 1; index++)); do echo \$index; done"
```

that gets converted to a single string. First, the quotes are removed *locally*, then ssh concatenates arguments to generate a single string to pass to the remote shell, so we get:

```
zsh -lc for ((index=1; index <= 1; index++)); do echo $index; done
```

Here, only the `for` is given as an argument to `-c`; following that we have subsequent commands going onto `zsh`'s argv, and then shell syntax that the remote shell is going to be confused/surprised by.

Comment: Thanks Charles. I would have marked this as the answer but Jens' answer was more concise and didn't require a significant rewrite of what I was doing. I will be using stdin approach going forward as I like that the most.